# Is there a way to distinguish between the user photo stream and a shared one?

Tags: ios, cocoa, alassetslibrary

I’m trying to show Photo Streams using `ALAssetsLibrary`, but I haven’t find a way to know if a given `ALAssetsGroup` is the user photo stream (the one named “My Photo Stream”) or a shared one (arbitrary named by the user). Neither I have find how to know if the user created the shared photo stream or it was shared with him/her.

The only “clues” I have been able to find is that “My Photo Stream” is always sorted by date, but other streams might also be. The `editable` property is always `NO` for the streams I have tested with (in Photos.app you can edit shared photo streams, but not “My Photo Stream”, which is automatically managed). `valueForProperty:` doesn’t provided that many keys, and no key seems to provide much information (the URL looks like any other assets library URL).

I will not want to use the name (“My Photo Stream”) because our international users might have very different names, and Apple might have change it at any moment.

I also have noticed that it is always the first photo stream to be returned when enumerating the `ALAssetsGroup` from a library, but I haven’t found any documented evidence of this (it seems that the groups are returned in the order they were added). I have tested disabling and enabling the user photo stream from the Preferences and it keeps appearing the first… but only if it is enabled.

Other idea I haven’t tested is using `+ disableSharedPhotoStreamsSupport` after I have enumerated the groups once, and then enumerate again, since the only photo stream left will be the user’s. But there is no `+ enableSharedPhotoStreamsSupport`, so I will lose all the possible notification for those shared streams “forever”.

Does someone have some insight? Have someone managed to properly use the shared photo streams?